# Javascript method in Function Error with "is not a function"

Tags: javascript, scope, bind, ecmascript-5

I've been learning basic Javascript concept with class.
I'm trying it with ES5 syntax.

By the way, I'm stuck with this problem.
I defined a class with function declaration. And Defined a method in that class.

```js
const Vehicle = function() {
  this.passengers = [];
  console.log('Vehicle created');

  const addPassenger = function(p) {
    this.passengers.push(p);
  }
}

const v = new Vehicle();

v.addPassenger("Frank");
v.addPassenger("Zim");
console.log(v.passengers);
```

But when I call it with its instance, I got the error. I think the problem is bind...But I have no idea where and which one should I bind.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you ever tried to copy a screenshot into your editor and edit it?

Comment: Please add an actual code snippet instead of a screenshot

Comment: It has to be `this.addPassenger =` instead of `const addPassenger`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently only declaring the `addPassenger` function as a constant inside the function.

To "make the function part of class", use **this**

```
this.addPassenger = function(p) {
////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function inside the vehicle function using `const or function` syntax, it doesn't belong to the instance variable and is private to the constructor function. In order to use it from the instace object you need to define it for the instance like

```js
const Vehicle = function() {
  this.passengers = [];
  console.log('Vehicle created');

  this.addPassenger = function(p) {
    this.passengers.push(p);
  }
}

const v = new Vehicle();

v.addPassenger("Frank");
v.addPassenger("Zim");
console.log(v.passengers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `const` with `this`

```js
const Vehicle = function() {
  this.passengers = [];
  console.log('Vehicle created');
  this.addPassenger = function(p) {
    this.passengers.push(p);
  }
}

const v = new Vehicle();

v.addPassenger("Frank");
v.addPassenger("Zim");
console.log(v.passengers);
```